# Stored procedure to make bulk updates

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, t-sql, azure-sql-database

Please help me understand how to work around the following error:

> (Line 16):    Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

The purpose of this stored procedure is for the user to input an "Acquiring" ID to be used to UPDATE/overwrite an "Acquired" ID. Very simple. But I want to do this for a large number of tables, some of which have trigger constraints that need to be disabled. I originally used subqueries instead of "update table set ID = @ID2 where ID = @ID1", but that threw the error above so then I tried to use a temp table instead and I'm still running into this error.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PartnerRemapTest2]
    (@AcquiringPartnerID int,
     @AcquiredPartnerID int)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    CREATE TABLE #TempPartnerRemap
    (
        ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
        AcquiringPartnerID int,
        AcquiredPartnerID int
    )

    INSERT INTO #TempPartnerRemap (AcquiringPartnerID, AcquiredPartnerID)
    VALUES (@AcquiringPartnerID, @AcquiredPartnerID)
    
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        BEGIN TRY
            ALTER TABLE [AVTestOLD].[dbo].[Individuals] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

            UPDATE R
            SET PartnerID = @AcquiringPartnerID
            FROM dbo.Individuals R
            INNER JOIN #TempPartnerRemap ON R.PartnerID = #TempPartnerRemap.AcquiredPartnerID

            UPDATE R2
            SET PartnerID = @AcquiringPartnerID
            FROM dbo.SurveyResults R2
            INNER JOIN #TempPartnerRemap ON R2.PartnerID = #TempPartnerRemap.AcquiredPartnerID

            -- ETC ETC

            COMMIT TRANSACTION
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SELECT
                ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
                ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END CATCH

        DROP TABLE #TempPartnerRemap
    END
```

Comment: Please edit and tag the database engine you’re using (I assume SQL Server?), that helps people with knowledge about that specific product to find it easier

Comment: You need to check your tables for triggers as there are no sub-queries in the code shown.

Comment: Nope - this path will only lead to tears. Firstly, your code eats errors and then returns them as a "regular" resultset. Your caller has no idea that an error actually occurred. Altering constraints to accomplish a task is also a terrible idea - that affects any connection using the table. And "large number of tables" suggests you will need dynamic sql - you will need help to write, test, and debug. Quite frankly I don't understand why you need a temp table either.

Comment: And it is suspicious that you alter a table using a 3-part name. That implies your procedure is in a different database than "AVTestOLD" and adds the complication of a hard-coded database name - which will become more apparent when you want to use multiple environments (development, test, production, client1, client2, etc.)

Comment: Can you please update the error message to match the current query, you said the query changed, tell us which line the error occurs on. It is clearly a derivative issue, but we need something solid to start from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

The problem is not directly in the code you have shown, unless the "tables" are really malformed views.  I am guessing that is not the case.  But if they are really views then check the definition of the views for flaws in the logic.

Much more likely are `update` triggers on the table.  And in SQL Server, this means that the trigger is assuming that `inserted` and/or `updated` has only one row.  Typically, this is something like this:

```
declare @something <sometype>;

set @something = (select <some column> from inserted);
```

Voila!  Big time failure if more than one row is inserted -- with the exactly error you are getting.

So, you need to look at the triggers on the table.  Unfortunately, if this is the case, then you should check **all** triggers in your system -- or at least all triggers written by anyone who created or modified this one.  This does not tend to be a one-off error.  You will need to review all trigger code to be sure the code does not make the "only one row" assumption.

I wish that SQL Server at least generated a warning in the obvious cases where this occurs.  It is a common problem.

Comment: You don't get a warning because it is perfectly valid right up until the point that multiple rows are retrieved. You get used to it once you're broken the rules a few times, the alternative would be for a lot of simple code to have TOP and ORDER BY clauses, just to make the warning go away, but how do I TOP or ORDER BY when using SELECT to deliberately assign variables and there is no FROM clause... It just opens another can of worms

Comment: Thanks @gordon, you were right there was a trigger with an only one row assumption I temporarily disabled (wasn't otherwise applicable with this update)

Answer (score 0):

thanks so much for the help. As suggested, I went through the triggers for affected tables and identified a default value trigger on a certain table that was throwing the error message. I temporarily disabled it (and re-enabled) and that did the trick. Thanks!